# Laravel API patch method

Tags: php, laravel, curl, sql-update

I am developing a laravel api and sucessfully made gets, posts, deletes and i am now trying to do the **update** method using PATCH.

Here is my first try:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $taxes = taxes::find($id);
    $taxes ->fill($request->only(['$request']));
    $taxes->save();
}
```

And testing it with the follow url on postman

> ****.local/api/taxes/1?description=test

This obviously doesnt work, i tought i would be able to see the error but i am currently on a different machine but hopefully someone can guide me to correct path to make this update method.

Dont forget its an api, no views/forms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the body of the query (so the variables you want to change) in the `x-www-form-urlencoded` tab of the `Body` tab for your request in Postman.

You can find a screenshot here: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/987644Sanstitre1.jpg (waiting for imgur to be back online)

You also have an issue in your method, your code should be the following:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $taxes = taxes::find($id);
    $taxes ->fill($request->only(['description', 'anyotherfield', '...']));
    $taxes->save();
}
```

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, does the update method seems correct to you ?

Comment: What if i want to update the field that is in the url and not manually add it on the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Could be to do with this line: `$request->only(['$request'])`, as your request is unlikely to have a parameter called `$request`. You might've been meaning to use `$request->all()` (all input) or `$request->only('description', 'etc.')` which will whitelist given paramters.

Probably should give your model a singular name, and capitalize it.

```
Tax::findOrFail($id)->update($request->only('description'))
```

Comment: It worked, what if i want to update the field that is in the url and not manually add it on the code ?